# using http cache in angularjs-rails-resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using the [angularjs-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) project to wrap my http rest services.
One thing I didn't find in documentation is regarding cache, some of my methods should access the server only once and cache their response.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass options to `$http` through your resource configuration (i.e. `httpConfig`) like so:

```
return railsResourceFactory({
  url: '/books',
  name: 'book',
  httpConfig: {
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Comment: And how can I invalidate the cache ?

Comment: You'll need to provide your own cache mechanism (see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2079#issuecomment-14216841)). Here's one popular replacement for Angular's $cacheFactory that works with `$http`: https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#using-angular-cache-with-http